# Could not connect to the endpoint url AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, octopus-deploy

I am trying to deploy an application into AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Octopus Deploy. But the deployment is failed. It is showing the following errors. How to resolve this?

```
    upload failed: .\RandomQuotes-1.0.0.Deployments-6.zip to s3://octopus-beanstalk-demoproject/RandomQuotes-1.0.0.Deployments-6.zip Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://octopus-beanstalk-demoproject.s3./RandomQuotes-1.0.0.Deployments-6.zip" 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:24Info
Creating application version RandomQuotes-1.0.0.Deployments-6 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:35Error
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://elasticbeanstalk./#{US East}.amazonaws.com" 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:44Error
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://elasticbeanstalk./#{US East}.amazonaws.com" 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
OperationStopped: Could not find the environment Development in the application Random Quotes 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
At C:\Users\nithyaneetha\Work\20200703102951-13-10\Script.ps1:17 char:11 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
+           throw "Could not find the environment $environment in the a ... 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
at Wait-ForEnvironmentToBeReady, C:\Users\nithyaneetha\Work\20200703102951-13-10\Script.ps1: line 17 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\nithyaneetha\Work\20200703102951-13-10\Script.ps1: line 113 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\nithyaneetha\Work\20200703102951-13-10\Bootstrap.Script.ps1: line 1574 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:46Error
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:47Fatal
The remote script failed with exit code 1 
July 3rd 2020 16:01:47Fatal
The action Depoy on the Octopus Server failed
```

Comment: Do you have an environment setup with the name `Development`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have an error in your configuration.

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://elasticbeanstalk./#{US East}.amazonaws.com"

There's an unreplaced variable (#{US EAST}) in the endpoint URL. Do you have a variable named "US East" defined? If so, it  could be an escaping iss as there's a / before the variable syntax.